# How to get deterministic value of global step variable (strictly after or strictly before increment)

Tags: python, tensorflow

Consider the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

global_step = tf.train.create_global_step()
x = tf.Variable(100.0)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
train_op = optimizer.minimize(x, global_step=global_step)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    step, _ = sess.run([global_step, train_op])
    print(step)
```

The output I got was '1', but I think nothing stops Tensorflow from giving me '0' instead, i.e. the value of the global step variable before the 'assign' op that increments it in the `train_op`. I actually have another, more complicated, Tensorflow program that exhibits this behavior, where the global step value I get from `Session.run([global_step, train_op])` is off-by-one between two machines where I run it.

For the global step variable, how can I definitively get its value from before the `train_op` or definitively get its value from after the `train_op`?

I know I can do a `sess.run([global_step])` separately before or after `sess.run([train_op])` but I would like to do as much as possible within a single `session.run()` if doesn't involve overly complicating the code. I know I can get the the pre-increment value by assigning `global_step` to another variable and making a control dependency between the `tf.assign` and `train_op`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

global_step = tf.train.create_global_step()
global_step2 = tf.get_variable('step-mirror', dtype=global_step.dtype, 
shape=global_step.shape)
global_step2 = tf.assign(global_step2, global_step)
x = tf.Variable(100.0)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
with tf.control_dependencies([global_step2]):
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(x, global_step=global_step)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    step, _ = sess.run([global_step2, train_op])
    print(step)
```

But I'm looking for a simpler way, perhaps a Tensorflow feature that I'm missing for specifying evaluating a variable from before any assignment on it.

EDIT: In response to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53002190/how-to-get-deterministic-value-of-global-step-variable-strictly-after-or-strict#comment93215051_53007892), this does not work, and it prints '1' instead of '0':

```
import tensorflow as tf

global_step = tf.train.create_global_step()
x = tf.Variable(100.0)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
with tf.control_dependencies([global_step]):
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(x, global_step=global_step)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    step, _ = sess.run([global_step, train_op])
    print(step)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to read the global step after the train_op:

```
import tensorflow as tf

global_step = tf.train.create_global_step()
x = tf.Variable(100.0)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
train_op = optimizer.minimize(x, global_step=global_step)

with tf.control_dependencies([train_op]):
    global_step_value = global_step.read_value()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    step, _ = sess.run([global_step_value, train_op])
    print(step)
```

Here `global_step_value` is not a variable anymore. It is a tensor with the value of `global_step` after `train_op` has been calculated. This is described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/variables) under "Using variables".

Comment: I tried your solution and it works. Now, when `train_op` is also wanted, I need to evaluate `global_step_value`, but when `train_op` is not wanted I need to evaluate `global_step` as evaluating `global_step_value` entails evaluation of `train_op`. So, it seems cleaner if there is a way to specify evaluating `global_step` _before any_ evaluation of train_op. This way, I don't have to care about `train_op` when I evaluate the global step and I have a uniform way to evaluate it. I wonder if this is possible. Using a `tf.control_dependencies` in the opposite direction doesn't help.

Comment: Making train_op have a control dependency on a global_step_value tensor should work. Why doesn't it for you?

Comment: @AlexandrePassos It doesn't work. That's why I said "Using a `tf.control_dependencies` in the opposite direction doesn't help".

Comment: You need to put the entire forward and backward pass inside the control_dependencies block, not just the train_op itself, to make this work. Sorry for not being clearer earlier.

Comment: @AlexandrePassos What do you mean by 'forward pass' and 'backward pass'? In terms of code, what variables are you referring to? Do you have code?

Comment: I mean your entire model definition. Literally everything in a control_dependencies block